# Subversion "copy link"

Tags: svn

Is it possible, using subversion, to have a special kind of link that creates a copy of the destination when checked out, instead of a reference/symlink?

I would like to have my template jboss configuration on a svn directory "/jboss/server/default/mycfg". i would like to have links ("mycfg01","mycfg02","mycfg03",..) that are identical to "mycfg", so i can edit in only one place, but when i check out, i'd like each directory to be a diferent copy, with its own runtime information (log files, etc).

Comment: Please expand your question with an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be interested in [subversion externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html).